# rxjs: how to create an Observable that yields true on success and false on error

Tags: rxjs

I want to create an Observable that subscribes to another Observable and yields true on success and false on error.

This is my solution:

```
new Observable ((observer: Observer<boolean>) => {
  obs().subscribe (() => {
    observer.next (true);
  }, error => {
    observer.next (false);
  })
});
```

But I think there must be an easier solution without "new Observable".
Something like:

```
obs().pipe (
  map (() => true),
  catchError(() => of(false))
);
```

But that leaves just typescript errors:

error TS2322: Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'boolean | Observable'.

Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type Observable'.

Type 'boolean | {}' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

I am using:
rxjs 5.5.2
typescript 2.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it was a problem with imports, now this works:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

obs ().map (() => true).catch (() => Observable.of (false));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try catching the exception and returning false

```
obs().catch(()=> of(false))
     .map(value=>{
         if(!value){
             return false;
         }
         return true;
     );
```

if the value is not truthy then return false, if it is truthy return a new observable of true.

Comment: Ok, but if it works it is more komplex and confusing than my first solution.

Comment: I disagree. plus it eliminates having that subscriptions inside the new observable you create which could create memory leaks. You may very well be able to remove the switch map and instead just use map. that probably will make it clearer.

Comment: Its the same as my second example just the other way round. But that does not work on rxjs 5.5.2. There you have to use pipe and catchError. Maybe I have a typescript problem.